# Restricted definition of primitive recursive function

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

I'm reading Peter Smith's introduction to Gödel's Theorems. He defines a primitive recursive (PR) function as:

- Zero, projection, successor functions
- Closed under composition
- Closed under primitive recursion, defined as

$$f(x_1, ..., x_n, Sy) = g(x_1, ..., x_n, y, f(x_1, ..., x_n, y))$$

I was wondering what the class of functions is if you restrict this to not use y:

$$f(x_1, ..., x_n, Sy) = g(x_1, ..., x_n, f(x_1, ..., x_n, y))$$

This seems like it should be more restrictive (I can't obviously get predecessor from this, but I can get multiplication), but I can't prove it.

What family of functions do you get from this?

Comment: If you can implement a pairing function under these constraints, then you don't lose anything other than convenience.

Comment: Can't you define multiplication by $x \times 0 = 0$ and $x \times Sy = (x \times y) + x$?

Comment: Oh, of course - somehow I'd convinced myself I needed +y, not +x. Thanks!

Comment: What about predecessor? Is it possible to prove that predecessor is not definable in this framework?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: predecessor is definable, but it's a bit tricky. See *A Reduction of the Recursion Scheme* by  M. D. Gladstone JSL, Vol. 32, No. 4 (1967). Available on JSTOR [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2270177)

Comment: @RobArthan - Brilliant! The reference answers perfectly the question and it's also very interesting. I think that you can write an answer about this, it deserves to be written and I'll upvote it (not only me, I guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! This kind of recursion was considered by R. Robinson in *Primitive Recursive Functions* Bull. AMS, vol 53 (1947) pp. 925-942 (available [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-10/S0002-9904-1947-08911-4/S0002-9904-1947-08911-4.pdf)). Robinson called your restricted recursion scheme "pure recursion". The functions $x+y$, $xy$ and $x^y$ are all definable by pure recursion and hence so is the very handy function $0^x$, which is the characteristic function of the set $\{0\}$ (or $\{ n \mid n > 0\}$ depending on your conventions).

Robinson observed that if you can give pure recursive definitions of a pairing function $\langle, \rangle : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and projection functions $\lambda, \rho : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda(\langle x, y\rangle) &=x \\
\rho(\langle x, y\rangle) &=y
\end{align*}
$$

then pure recursion is equivalent to unrestricted primitive recursion.
(The notation here is mine, not Robinson's.)
To see this (omitting the parameters $x_1, \ldots, x_n$), if we want
to define $f$ such that:

$$
\begin{align*}
f(0)&= h \\
f(S(y)) &= g(y, f(y))
\end{align*}
$$

we can define $f'$ by the pure recursion scheme:

$$
\begin{align*}
f'(0)&= \langle 0, h \rangle\\
f'(S(y)) &= \langle S(\lambda(f'(y))), g(\lambda(f'(y)), \rho(f'(y)))\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

and then put $f(x) = \rho(f'(x))$.

Robinson proposed the following definitions of the pairing and projection functions.

$$
\begin{align*}
\langle x, y \rangle &= (x + y)^2 + x\\
\lambda(x) &= x - \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor^2 \\
\rho(x) &= \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor - \lambda(x)
\end{align*}
$$

The definition of $\langle,\rangle$ can be obtained by composing addition and multiplication and so it is pure recursive.
Robinson noted that $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor$ is definable by the pure recursion scheme:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lfloor \sqrt{0} \rfloor &= 0 \\
\lfloor \sqrt{S(y)} \rfloor &= \lfloor \sqrt{y} \rfloor + 0^{(S(\lfloor \sqrt{y} \rfloor))^2 - S(y)}
\end{align*}
$$

(the exponent $(S(\lfloor \sqrt{y} \rfloor))^2 - S(y)$ here is $0$ iff
$S(y)$ is a perfect square, so we add $1$ in that case and $0$ otherwise).
Subtraction $x - y$ (for $x \ge y$) can be defined by the following
pure recursion scheme using the predecessor function $P$.

$$
\begin{align*}
x - 0 &= x\\
x - S(y) &= P(x - y)
\end{align*}
$$

Thus pure recursion is equivalent to unrestricted primitive recursion iff
$P$ can be defined by pure recursion. This was subsequently proved by M. D. Gladstone in
*A Reduction of the Recursion Scheme* JSL, Vol. 32, No. 4 (1967) pp. 505-508 (available [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2270177)).
The key to Gladstone's proof is a pure recursive definition
of a function $C(x, y)$ such that $C(x, y) = 0$ iff $x \le y$.
Using, this Gladstone defines a function $f$ by

$$
\begin{align*}
f(0, y) &= y \\
f(S(x), y)&= \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
0\mbox{, if $C(y, f(x, y)) = 0$}\\
f(x, y) +1 \mbox{, otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
$$

and then $P(x) = f(x, x)$. (To see this prove by induction on $x$ that
for $1 \le x \le y$, $f(x, y) = P(x)$.) I refer you to Gladstone's short and clear paper for the clever technique he uses to define $C(x, y)$.